# jQuery onchange/onfocus select box to display an image?

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-plugins, onchange, onfocus

I need some help finding a jQuery plugin which will allow me to display an image preview from a select list of images - onfocus/onchange..

Example:

```
<select name="image" id="image" class="inputbox" size="1">
   <option value=""> - Select Image - </option>
   <option value="image1.jpg">image1.jpg</option>
   <option value="image2.jpg">image2.jpg</option>
   <option value="image3.jpg">image3.jpg</option>
</select>

<div id="imagePreview">
   displays image here
</div>
```

Has anyone come across something like this? I've tried searching for it to no avail..

Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not sure you need a plugin to deal with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#image").change(function() {
        var src = $(this).val();

        $("#imagePreview").html(src ? "<img src='" + src + "'>" : "");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but it also does the same as i have already made.
Some thing else...?

Comment: I don't think the whole `src` line is really necessary, can be easily replaced by `$(this).val()`

Comment: @negative — In the event handler, `this` refers to the <select> node, not the <option>.  It's a separate line so that it doesn't need executed twice (improving performance).

Comment: my point is `$('select').val()` will return value of its selected option, searching for a selector would slow down performance.

Comment: @negative — D'oh!  Now you've got me wondering why I wrote it this way in the first place.  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a plugin for this, but it is fairly trivial to do "by hand"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#image').change(function(){
            $('#imagePreview').html('<img src="'+$('#image').val()+'"/>');
    });
});
```

You should add a validation for non-existent images and such. Your mileage may vary. etc.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need a plugin?

Would something simple like below work?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery Image</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#image").change(function() {
     $("#imagePreview").empty();
     if ( $("#image").val()!="" ){
        $("#imagePreview").append("<img src=\"" + $("#image").val()  + "\" />");
     }
     else{
        $("#imagePreview").append("displays image here");
     }
   });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="image" id="image" class="inputbox" size="1">
   <option value=""> - Select Image - </option>
   <option value="image1.jpg">image1.jpg</option>
   <option value="image2.jpg">image2.jpg</option>
   <option value="image3.jpg">image3.jpg</option>
</select>

<div id="imagePreview">
   displays image here
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative method with AJAX. I have not tested it, but googled about the topic. Here are some notes:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1107236.aspx

Server-side

```
response.contentType('image/jpeg');
response.binaryWrite(imageBytes);
```

[Displaying ad content from Respose.WriteFile()/ Response.ContentType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234/displaying-ad-content-from-respose-writefile-response-contenttype)

http://www.dotnetperls.com/response-writefile

```
Response.WriteFile usage:           10.680 s
Byte[] cache, Response.BinaryWrite:  0.094 s
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing here pure javascript version to change image using dropdown :-

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var Path='http://www.domainname.com/images/';
function CngColor(obj){
index=obj.selectedIndex;
if (index<1){ return; }
document.getElementById('Img1').src=Path+obj.options[index].value;
}

</script></head>
<body>

<select onchange="CngColor(this);" >
<option >Select</option>
<option value="Zero.gif" >Zero</option>
<option value="One.gif" >1</option>
<option value="Two.gif" >2</option>
<option value="Three.gif" >3</option>
<option value="Four.gif" >4</option>
</select>

<img id="Img1" src="http://www.domainname.com/images/Blank.gif" width=100 height=100 >

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A small contribution, I went through something similar and created this code, how to use the select options and display some images using jquery, it works on mobile too !!

```js
$(".my_select").change(function() {
   var value_my_select = $(this).val();
   $(".my_select").css({"background":"url(https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=My+image+" +value_my_select + ") no-repeat","background-size": "100% 100%"})
}).trigger( "change" ); 

//$(".my_select").val("3333").trigger( "change" );
```

```css
select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  color: transparent;
}

.my_select * {
  color: #000;
  height: 30px;
}

select,option {
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

select, option:checked {  font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="my_select">
      <option>1111</option>
      <option selected>2222</option>
      <option>3333</option>
      </select>
```

you can also see this here: https://jsfiddle.net/diversalizando/40rec3w1/19/