# change image based on drop-down option

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery onchange/onfocus select box to display an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984484/jquery-onchange-onfocus-select-box-to-display-an-image)

Looking to be able to change an image dynamically based on the selection option dropdown with an id of "main"

I came across this code which finds the text not the select value, which is exactly what I want. I just need to connect to the image.

```
alert( 'Text is: ' + $('#attribute119 :selected').text() );
```

The image is formatted like this

```
 <img src="mainimage.jpg" id="main">
```

How would I dynamically change the image based on the option name selected when the form changes?  My form looks something like this.

```
<form name="pds">
<select name="DropDownName" id="attribute119" >
<option value="0">Choose an option...</option>
<option value="2">blue</option>
<option value="3">green</option>
<option value="4">red</option>
</select>
</form>
```

The images will be named like this.

```
 "1232_blue.jpg, 1232_red.jpg,etc.".
```

The color name is followed by the last "_" in the filename

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('#attribute119').change(function () {
  $('#main').attr('src', '1232_' + $('#attribute119 :selected').text() + '.jpg');
});
```

Comment: also use $.trim() before passing the value as part of the name !