# Change Font Style (bold, Italic, bold italic) in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [change font style in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607280/change-font-style-in-c)

HI there I want to change the font style of a label to either bold, italic, etc.. using a dropdownlist in an aspx page. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here, because nothing seem to work.

My Code:

```
public void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var select= font1.SelectedItem.Value;
    if(select=="Bold")
    {
        // I have the following methods of doing this; None works for me.
        label1.Style["Font-Weight"]="bold";
        //I also tried this:
        label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        //and this:
        this.label1.Font= new Font(this.label1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    }
}
```

When using .Font I get errors for invalid arguments, that the arguments for Font must be like this: Font(string, float). Also, keep in mind that the method of putting the actual size in the argument list is not what i want to do. Like this

```
label1.Font=new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold);
//I don't want to change the font family or sixe of the label's text
```

So thats what I have, I'm in a jam. Please enlighten me. Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607280/change-font-style-in-c/5607319#comment-6385717

Answer (score 5):

A better approach would be to change the *CssClass* of the label and have different CSS classes defined that match the styling you want (in a separate CSS file that would be included  in your page).

Much of what you describe is normally done on the client side (browser) using CSS and javascript, where you don't need to round-trip to the server in order to get UI changes.

Comment: Although `CssClass` is probably the best way, you can still do this via the label attribute.add property correct?

Comment: @Nick - You can add a `style` attribute with the CSS on it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using CSS and simply applying a class.  You wouldn't even need to do this server-side.

A little bit of client-side code:

```
 <style>
   .bold { font-weight: bold; }
 </style>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('#font1').change( function() {
     if ($(this).val().matches(/bold/i)) {
        $('#label1').addClass('bold');
     }
     else {
        $('#label1').removeClass('bold');
     }
     ... handle italic, etc. ...
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: My Application is server-side development. I don't want to use javascript (can't anyway).